# $_POST value not complete in php file

Tags: php, ajax, database, forms

He guyz,

I am very confused because of what is happening with my form values.

At first I created a simple html form, of which I convert the values to a string. Below is part of the code in my document.ready

```
 var fbid = $("#fbid").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var address1 = $("#address1").val();
    var address2 = $("#address2").val();
    var city = $("#city").val();
    var postal = $("#postal").val();
    var countries = $("#countries").val();
    var dataString = 'fbid=' + fbid + '&name=' + name + '&address1=' + address1 + '&address2=' + address2 + '&city=' + city + '&postal=' + postal + '&countries=' + countries
```

So far so good. I then use the following code to upload this to a php file in order to insert the data into my database

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "*http://www.url.com/file.php*",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
```

Now somehow, only my last value is giving problems. this select input only puts the first 5 characters in my database. When I tried it with a text input, it shows only 3 characters(which I thought was really weird). I tried to debug and find where the problem was:

- Changing the order of my string (last and second last value) resulted in the second last value not displaying correctly (so countries was posted succesfully(also weird:P)
- I deleted all content in my php file and replaced it with

**$countries=$_POST['countries'];
echo "$countries";**

this resulted in, also, only the first 5 characters to be displayed

1. I used console.log to view the string and here the full content is displayed

so it almost looks like something goes wrong in between sending the string and my php file receiving it

I honestly have know idea what is going wrong here. Would love some help as I have spend the best part of a WEEK on this now!

Bye,
Chris

Comment: What do you get in your console?

Comment: Edit your post. Add 'Expected Results', and 'Actual Results';

Comment: There's `$(form).serialize()`. But you can keep on trying

Comment: it shows the correct value..in my case countries=Netherlands. The database (and when I checked $_POST for countries) shows only Nethe @CharlotteDunois

Comment: What's the contents of `file.php`?

Comment: What's the length for your column in your database?

Comment: Is the request correct in the browser's developer tool (network tab)?

Comment: <?php
$connection = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'db', 'pass'); // Establishing Connection with Server..
$db = mysql_select_db("youddress", $connection); // Selecting Database
//Fetching Values from URL
$fbid=$_POST['fbid'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$address1=$_POST['address1'];
$address2=$_POST['address2'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$postal=$_POST['postal'];
$countries=$_POST['countries'];

echo "Form Submitted Succesfully";

?>

Comment: @jessica length is 60. What do you mean with expected and actual results?

Comment: I think your dataString should be  var dataString = 'fbid:' + fbid + ', name:' + name + ', address1:' + address1 + ', address2:' + address2 + ', city:' + city + ', postal:' + postal + ', countries:' + countries;

Comment: @CharlotteDunois but you cannot join strings without plus sign, right?

Comment: @ASTeam I thought you were making a JSON object - but if you want a string then is the delimiter `&` and not a comma for HTTP parameters.

Comment: I don't follow, so in what way is the 'fbid=' + fbid + etc incorrect? Sorry guys as you might figure I'm a little new to javascript

Comment: @CharlotteDunois yeah you're right, you should use & for HTTP, i messed    it with the format that I use to send in ajax data: {'test':test, ..}.

Answer (score 0):

Since when you swapped the fields, countries value got inserted correctly, but the second last value was truncated. This means that you are somehow hitting the limit in terms of the data that you post.

While highly unlikely, this could be something you want to test as well. Try the following:

1. Make a regular post, without ajax and check if all the data is getting posted correctly. If no, then most probably you have an incorrect `post_max_size` set in your apache config or htaccess.
2. If test above works, then regular post is fine and it has something to do with ajax. Ensure that your data is not going as url param (looking at the code it should not). However first post each values individually to see if they are going through.

With the results of these tests you should be able to discern where the problem is. Your code is fine, I strongly feel it must be something with configs.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was filling in the form in the android emulator of apache cordova. Now when I wanted to test everything today, and copied it to a url to work on it at the office, everything was posted correctly! Will try to see what other emulators do and determine if the problem lies there